# Delete photoshop layer doesn't ask for confirmation

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I don't know if this is a repeated question or not but somehow when I delete the Photoshop layer it doesn't prompt a confirmation box if I want to delete or not.

Is it a normal behaviour or do I need to do some settings?

Advance Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities...

- Holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key when clicking the little trash icon on the Layers Panel will *bypass* the confirmation dialog.
- The conformation dialog itself has a little `Don't Show Again` checkbox. If you ticked that, the confirmation won't show. If you *want* it to show again, go to `Photoshop > Preferences > General` and click the `Reset all Warning Dialogs` button.

[image]